# Springboot + spring data Mongo

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using in my Project the springboot 1.4.0.RELEASE and I put in my pom the next dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

so can I change this dependency to use the newest with no problem?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure yes. These are the [news in the 1.9](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#new-features.1-9-0):

> - The following annotations have been enabled to build own, composed annotations: @Document, @Id, @Field, @Indexed, @CompoundIndex,
>     @GeoSpatialIndexed, @TextIndexed, @Query, @Meta.
> - Support for Projections in repository query methods.
> - Support for Query by Example.
> - Out-of-the-box support for java.util.Currency in object mapping.
> - Add support for the bulk operations introduced in MongoDB 2.6.
> - Upgrade to Querydsl 4.
> - Assert compatibility with MongoDB 3.0 and MongoDB Java Driver 3.2 (see: MongoDB 3.0 Support).

You just exclude from `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` and overwritte it

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```